# Multiple wordlists in csh script foreach loop

Tags: shell, csh

I have a Cshell script that I am modifying to have related input and output locations. 
the functionality all happens in a foreach loop like so:

```
set INPUT_LOCATION_LIST = "loc1 loc2 loc3 loc4"
foreach location ($INPUT_LOCATION_LIST)
#***Do some stuff ***
end
```

I would like to have an output list with different values than the input list but traverse through it each iteration through the foreach loop. The man for foreach simply has

```
foreach name (wordlist)
```

as the definition. so only dealing with a single one. my current thought on dealing with it is have the wordlist contain both input and output location and then parse it out in the script:

```
set INPUT_LOCATION_LIST = "loc1;out1 loc2;out2 loc3;out3 loc4;out4"
```

so im wondering if anyone has a better way to do that.

Comment: The `c` tag is for C programming language related questions. `csh` while named the "C Shell" has nothing to do with the C programming language. I removed that tag for you.

Comment: I must've typed C and shell as separate tags, my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through one list using `foreach` and through the other one by treating at like an array and using `shift`:

```
set INPUT_LOCATION_LIST = "loc1 loc2 loc3 loc4"
set OUT_LIST = (out1 out2 out3 out4)

foreach location ($INPUT_LOCATION_LIST)
    do_something $location $OUT_LIST[1]
    shift OUT_LIST
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally use csh, but your question caught my eye.  There's probably a solution with less steps, but this kind of thing worked in my version of csh:

```
foreach location ($INPUT_LOCATION_LIST)
    set one_word_with_space = ${location:s/;/ /}
    set loc_out = ($one_word_with_space)
    set loc = ${loc_out[1]}
    set out = ${loc_out[2]}
    ...
end
```

Basic idea is just to change the semi-colon separated string into a space-separated string, then parse that into an array.